# How do you set ANDROID_VENDOR_KEYS on an AOSP build?

Tags: android, android-source

I've generated a key pair I want to put into my source so they'll be compiled into ROM. The objective is to allow access via just these keys.

I just don't understand where I should put them. There are no existing examples as far as I can see. Where should I copy the key pair and how do I set the required env values on AOSP Android 7.1.2?

Comment: https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#ANDROID_VENDOR_KEYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've updated the docs recently (since this is more important now adb is a mainline module): https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#ANDROID_VENDOR_KEYS gives more details about how we do this at Google.